# Api Patch Request Error (400) React Asp.net Core

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

I'm trying to make Patch request like that but I'm getting 400.

```
const response = await actions.GetItemById({id:params.id});

      if (sepetString !== null) {
        const sepet = JSON.parse(sepetString);
        BasketPostVM.userId=sepet;
        BasketPostVM.ProductName=response.productId;
        try {
          const updateBasketResponse = await fetch('http://localhost:5187/api/Basket/updatebasket', {
            method: 'PATCH',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(BasketPostVM),
          });
  
          if (updateBasketResponse.ok) {
            console.log('Basket updated successfully');
            // Handle success if needed
          } else {
            console.error('Failed to update basket');
            // Handle failure if needed
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error while updating basket', error);
          // Handle error if needed
        }        
      }
```

Here is an Object Type for easily Patch

```
const BasketPostVM={
  userId:"",
  ProductName:"",
  productColors:"",
  productOptions:""
}
```

But the interesting thing is I can get answer with Postman like this:

[image: This].

Here is Asp.net Core Project I'm trying to reach here.

```
[HttpPatch,Route("updatebasket")]
public bool UpdateBasketItems([FromBody] BasketPostVM updatedbasket) 
{
    Basket existingBasket = dbcontext.BasketTable.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserID == updatedbasket.userId);

    if (existingBasket != null)
    {
        existingBasket.ProductIDs.Add(updatedbasket.ProductName); 
        existingBasket.ProductColor = updatedbasket.productColors;
        existingBasket.ProductOptions = updatedbasket.productOptions;

        dbcontext.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

Base Basket Class

```
    public class Basket
    {
           [Key]
           public int Id { get; set; }
           public string? UserID { get; set; }
           public string? UserID2 { get; set; }
           public List<string?> ProductIDs { get; set; } = new List<string?>();
           public string? ProductColor { get; set; }
           public string? ProductOptions { get; set; }
           public bool isSinged { get; set; }=false;
           public List<string?> OrderIDs { get; set; } = new List<string?>();



    }
```

View Model For Post

```
  public class BasketPostVM
  {
      public string? userId { get; set; }
      public string? ProductName { get; set; }
      public string? productColors { get; set; }
      public string? productOptions { get; set; }
  }
```

I'm expecting normal API response Like Postman gives.

Comment: if you `console.log(JSON.stringify(BasketPostVM))` in your code - what is the output

Comment: Is is related to cross-origin.  check your net work tab of developer console. what request is sent with parameters